# Strange errors regarding functions that return a specific class

Tags: c++

I am currently in the process of making a game engine in OpenGL. After manually implementing cameras I decided to transform them into a class. I found myself re-writing a few specific lines of code a lot so I decided to turn it into a function and store the function with the rest of my helpers. The function's objective is to loop through an array of cameras (VCamera) and find the main camera. (Noted that this function returns the camera class). I find this odd as this is a function that I was sure would experience no errors, so I was surprised when I saw multiple build errors regarding this file.

The errors are here: [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCnKA.png)

The line in question causing these errors is line twenty-one of the Helpers.h file (CODE BELOW).

Or, this line here: `VCamera GetMainCam(std::vector<VCamera> camArray);`

I find this especially odd as Intellisense doesn't see any errors either.

Usually, I can find a solution for these errors but this one has stumped me.

Noted I have all the code for each of the files below.

```
/* Helpers.h */

#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <vector>
/* NOTE: I imported the VCamera class here */
#include "VCamera.h"

namespace Vega
{
    enum LOGTYPE
    {
        LOG,
        LISTENER,
        EVENT
    };

    void log(LOGTYPE logType, std::string logStr);
    void escape(int exitCode, std::string exitMsg);
    void error(int errorCode, LPCWSTR errorMsg);
    bool pressed(int keyCode);
        /* This line is causing errors */
    VCamera GetMainCam(std::vector<VCamera> camArray);
}

/* Helpers.cpp */

#include "Helpers.h"

void Vega::log(LOGTYPE logType, std::string logStr)
{
    switch (logType)
    {
    case LOG:
        std::cout << "[LOG] " << logStr << "\n";
        break;
    case LISTENER:
        std::cout << "[LISTENER] " << logStr << "\n";
        break;
    case EVENT:
        std::cout << "[EVENT] " << logStr << "\n";
        break;
    }
}

void Vega::escape(int exitCode, std::string exitMsg)
{
    std::cout << "Exited with code " << exitCode << ". (" << exitMsg << ")" << "\n";
    exit(exitCode);
}

void Vega::error(int errorCode, LPCWSTR errorMsg)
{
    std::cout << "[ERROR] " << CW2A(errorMsg) << "\n";
    MessageBox(NULL, errorMsg, L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    escape(errorCode, "Process exited due to an abnormality.");
}

bool Vega::pressed(int keyCode)
{
    if (GetKeyState(keyCode) & 0x8000)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/* THIS IS THE FUNCTION */

Vega::VCamera Vega::GetMainCam(std::vector<VCamera> camArray)
{
    for (VCamera& cam : camArray)
    {
        if (cam.isMainCamera)
        {
            return cam;
        }
    }

    error(1, L"Failed to find any cameras with the 'main' identifier.");
}

/* VCamera.h */
#pragma once
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include "Dependencies.h"
#include "Helpers.h"

namespace Vega
{
    class VCamera
    {
    public:
        VCamera(bool isMainCam);

        bool isMainCamera;
        const int camSpeed = 1;
        glm::vec3 camPos;

        glm::mat4 GetView();
        void UpdatePos(glm::vec3 newPos);
    };
}

/* VCamera.cpp */
#include "VCamera.h"

Vega::VCamera::VCamera(bool isMainCam)
{
    isMainCamera = isMainCam;
    camPos = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
}

glm::mat4 Vega::VCamera::GetView()
{
    return glm::lookAt(camPos, glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
}

void Vega::VCamera::UpdatePos(glm::vec3 newPos)
{
    camPos = newPos;
}
```

To me at least, It seems that the compiler doesn't have any knowledge of what a VCamera is. Which is odd due to the fact that I included it at the top of Helpers.h.

If you need any more information I'd be happy to provide so.

Thanks, Archie.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Look at the first error.

Comment: you included a screenshot of your IDEs error summary. You need to find the tab that shows the full compiler error message. Include error messages as text in the question please

Comment: You have a circular inclusion problem. "VCamera.h" does not need "Helpers.h".

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to pass that vector by value?

Comment: @Bob__ I cleanup up the code by passing the vector by reference, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in fact a circular inclusion problem. I removed the include from the top of VCamera.h as it was unneeded and that was the fix.